# celery beat + django on Windows: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: django, windows-10, celery, ubuntu-18.04, celerybeat

**I already tried other solutions on the site and they didn't work**, also, many are old questions that reference the now obsolete django-celery-beat package. I'm on Django 3 and Celery 4 which should mean, according to the documentation of the latter, that I don't need anything extra to run Celery with Django anymore.

My project is structured so:

```
proj/
|- app1/
|- app2/
|- proj/
   |- settings.py
   |- ...
   |- celery.py
   |- tasks.py
```

(I also tried putting `tasks.py` in one of the apps.)

celery.py:

```py
import os
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab


os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "proj.settings")
app = Celery("proj")

app.config_from_object("django.conf:settings", namespace="CELERY")
app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **_):
    from .tasks import debug_task
    sender.add_periodic_task(crontab(), debug_task.apply_async())
```

tasks.py:

```py
from celery import shared_task


@shared_task
def debug_task():
    print("Task executed.")
```

What I do to try and run the project is:

1. `py manage.py runserver`,
2. `celery -A proj.celery beat`,
3. `celery -A proj.celery worker`.

On Ubuntu I'd run all three commands with detached `screen` sessions to run everything on the same terminal in case it's important, but I couldn't find any feasible alternative for Windows, so all three are executed in separate terminals opened after the previous one's command was already running. I tried putting "beat" and "worker" right after "celery" in case it mattered.
I also tried the same through PyCharm's run feature (for Django's server) and two separate terminal instances for the other two commands. If there's a better procedure to follow feel free to suggest it.

Output of Celery beat:

```
celery beat v4.4.0 (cliffs) is starting.
__    -    ... __   -        _
LocalTime -> 2020-03-14 16:48:32
Configuration ->
    . broker -> amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
    . loader -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
    . scheduler -> celery.beat.PersistentScheduler
    . db -> celerybeat-schedule
    . logfile -> [stderr]@%DEBUG
    . maxinterval -> 5.00 minutes (300s)
[2020-03-14 16:48:32,042: DEBUG/MainProcess] Setting default socket timeout to 30
[2020-03-14 16:48:32,044: INFO/MainProcess] beat: Starting...
[2020-03-14 16:48:32,288: DEBUG/MainProcess] Current schedule:
<ScheduleEntry: celery.backend_cleanup celery.backend_cleanup() <crontab: 0 4 * * * (m/h/d/dM/MY)>
[2020-03-14 16:48:32,288: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Ticking with max interval->5.00 minutes
[2020-03-14 16:48:32,292: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up in 5.00 minutes.
```

Output of Celery worker with the error:

```
[2020-03-14 16:49:50,319: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Preparing bootsteps.
[2020-03-14 16:49:50,326: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Building graph...
[2020-03-14 16:49:50,327: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: New boot order: {Timer, Hub, Pool, Autoscaler, Beat, StateDB, Consumer}
[2020-03-14 16:49:50,472: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Preparing bootsteps.
[2020-03-14 16:49:50,473: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Building graph...
[2020-03-14 16:49:50,593: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: New boot order: {Connection, Agent, Events, Heart, Mingle, Tasks, Control, Gossip, event loop}

 -------------- celery@MY-LATPTOPS-NAME v4.4.0 (cliffs)
--- ***** -----
-- ******* ---- Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0 2020-03-14 16:49:50
- *** --- * ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         proj:0x3f91ef8
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
- ** ---------- .> results:     disabled://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 4 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** -----
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . celery.accumulate
  . celery.backend_cleanup
  . celery.chain
  . celery.chord
  . celery.chord_unlock
  . celery.chunks
  . celery.group
  . celery.map
  . celery.starmap
  . proj.tasks.debug_task

[2020-03-14 16:49:50,600: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Starting Pool
[2020-03-14 16:49:50,614: WARNING/MainProcess] e:\path_to\my_project\venv38\lib\site-packages\billiard\pool.py:1022: UserWarning: Soft timeouts are not supported: on this platform: It does not have the SIGUSR1 signal.
  warnings.warn(UserWarning(
[2020-03-14 16:49:50,736: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2020-03-14 16:49:50,737: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Starting Consumer
[2020-03-14 16:49:50,738: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Connection
[2020-03-14 16:49:51,250: DEBUG/MainProcess] recreated blocker with handle 24
[2020-03-14 16:49:51,251: DEBUG/MainProcess] recreated blocker with handle 32
[2020-03-14 16:49:51,253: DEBUG/MainProcess] recreated blocker with handle 20
[2020-03-14 16:49:51,256: DEBUG/MainProcess] recreated blocker with handle 24
[2020-03-14 16:49:51,267: DEBUG/MainProcess] recreated blocker with handle 20
[2020-03-14 16:49:51,268: DEBUG/MainProcess] recreated blocker with handle 24
[2020-03-14 16:49:51,305: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] child process 3316 calling self.run()
[2020-03-14 16:49:51,309: DEBUG/MainProcess] recreated blocker with handle 24
[2020-03-14 16:49:51,310: DEBUG/MainProcess] recreated blocker with handle 28
[2020-03-14 16:49:51,315: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-3] child process 12052 calling self.run()
[2020-03-14 16:49:51,318: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-4] child process 13968 calling self.run()
[2020-03-14 16:49:51,360: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-2] child process 6336 calling self.run()
[2020-03-14 16:49:52,776: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
Trying again in 2.00 seconds...
```

As you can see the tasks is being seen from the worker, but is never executed.

I thought it might have something to do with the firewall so I retried after disabling it completely but nothing changed.

The error is clearly Windows-related but I need this to also work on a Ubuntu-18.04 instance, so if there's anything I need to change between the two systems please feel free to mention it.

**UPDATE**

Embarrassingly enough, it seems I had forgotten to set up RabbitMQ on this machine. Doing it got rid of the error message, but the task still doesn't seem to run as expected. The worker process now ticks approximately every second, and the initial output (similar to what shown above) correctly shows the debug task, but its output is never shown on any of the terminals (Django's server, celery beat and celery worker) even after several minutes of activity.
How can I confirm whether the task is running or not?

Here is the initial output `celery beat -A proj.celery -l DEBUG`:

```
celery beat v4.4.0 (cliffs) is starting.
__    -    ... __   -        _
LocalTime -> 2020-03-19 10:08:34
Configuration ->
    . broker -> amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
    . loader -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
    . scheduler -> celery.beat.PersistentScheduler
    . db -> celerybeat-schedule
    . logfile -> [stderr]@%DEBUG
    . maxinterval -> 5.00 minutes (300s)
[2020-03-19 10:08:34,789: DEBUG/MainProcess] Setting default socket timeout to 30
[2020-03-19 10:08:34,790: INFO/MainProcess] beat: Starting...
[2020-03-19 10:08:35,109: DEBUG/MainProcess] Current schedule:
<ScheduleEntry: celery.backend_cleanup celery.backend_cleanup() <crontab: 0 4 * * * (m/h/d/dM/MY)>
[2020-03-19 10:08:35,109: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Ticking with max interval->5.00 minutes
[2020-03-19 10:08:35,111: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up in 5.00 minutes.
```

This is the output of `celery worker -A proj.celery -l DEBUG`:

```
[2020-03-19 10:08:11,288: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Preparing bootsteps.
[2020-03-19 10:08:11,296: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Building graph...
[2020-03-19 10:08:11,297: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: New boot order: {StateDB, Beat, Timer, Hub, Pool, Autoscaler, Consumer}
[2020-03-19 10:08:11,475: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Preparing bootsteps.
[2020-03-19 10:08:11,475: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Building graph...
[2020-03-19 10:08:11,613: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: New boot order: {Connection, Events, Heart, Mingle, Gossip, Agent, Tasks, Control, event loop}

 -------------- celery@MY-LAPTOPS-NAME v4.4.0 (cliffs)
--- ***** -----
-- ******* ---- Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0 2020-03-19 10:08:11
- *** --- * ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         proj:0x4261e50
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
- ** ---------- .> results:     disabled://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 4 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** -----
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . celery.accumulate
  . celery.backend_cleanup
  . celery.chain
  . celery.chord
  . celery.chord_unlock
  . celery.chunks
  . celery.group
  . celery.map
  . celery.starmap
  . proj.tasks.debug_task

[2020-03-19 10:08:11,646: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Starting Pool
[2020-03-19 10:08:11,773: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2020-03-19 10:08:11,773: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Starting Consumer
[2020-03-19 10:08:11,774: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Connection
[2020-03-19 10:08:11,842: DEBUG/MainProcess] Start from server, version: 0.9, properties: {'capabilities': {'publisher_confirms': True, 'exchange_exchange_bindings': True, 'bas
ic.nack': True, 'consumer_cancel_notify': True, 'connection.blocked': True, 'consumer_priorities': True, 'authentication_failure_close': True, 'per_consumer_qos': True, 'direct
_reply_to': True}, 'cluster_name': 'rabbit@MY-LAPTOPS-NAME', 'copyright': 'Copyright (c) 2007-2020 Pivotal Software, Inc.', 'information': 'Licensed under the MPL 1.1. Website:
 https://rabbitmq.com', 'platform': 'Erlang/OTP 22.3', 'product': 'RabbitMQ', 'version': '3.8.3'}, mechanisms: [b'AMQPLAIN', b'PLAIN'], locales: ['en_US']
[2020-03-19 10:08:11,850: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//
[2020-03-19 10:08:11,855: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2020-03-19 10:08:11,856: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Events
[2020-03-19 10:08:11,911: DEBUG/MainProcess] Start from server, version: 0.9, properties: {'capabilities': {'publisher_confirms': True, 'exchange_exchange_bindings': True, 'bas
ic.nack': True, 'consumer_cancel_notify': True, 'connection.blocked': True, 'consumer_priorities': True, 'authentication_failure_close': True, 'per_consumer_qos': True, 'direct
_reply_to': True}, 'cluster_name': 'rabbit@MY-LAPTOPS-NAME', 'copyright': 'Copyright (c) 2007-2020 Pivotal Software, Inc.', 'information': 'Licensed under the MPL 1.1. Website:
 https://rabbitmq.com', 'platform': 'Erlang/OTP 22.3', 'product': 'RabbitMQ', 'version': '3.8.3'}, mechanisms: [b'AMQPLAIN', b'PLAIN'], locales: ['en_US']
[2020-03-19 10:08:11,924: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2020-03-19 10:08:11,945: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Heart
[2020-03-19 10:08:11,946: DEBUG/MainProcess] using channel_id: 1
[2020-03-19 10:08:11,961: DEBUG/MainProcess] Channel open
[2020-03-19 10:08:12,021: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2020-03-19 10:08:12,021: DEBUG/MainProcess] Timer wake-up! Next ETA 1.0 secs.
[2020-03-19 10:08:12,029: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Mingle
[2020-03-19 10:08:12,030: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2020-03-19 10:08:12,030: DEBUG/MainProcess] using channel_id: 1
[2020-03-19 10:08:12,074: DEBUG/MainProcess] Channel open
[2020-03-19 10:08:12,141: DEBUG/MainProcess] Start from server, version: 0.9, properties: {'capabilities': {'publisher_confirms': True, 'exchange_exchange_bindings': True, 'bas
ic.nack': True, 'consumer_cancel_notify': True, 'connection.blocked': True, 'consumer_priorities': True, 'authentication_failure_close': True, 'per_consumer_qos': True, 'direct
_reply_to': True}, 'cluster_name': 'rabbit@MY-LAPTOPS-NAME', 'copyright': 'Copyright (c) 2007-2020 Pivotal Software, Inc.', 'information': 'Licensed under the MPL 1.1. Website:
 https://rabbitmq.com', 'platform': 'Erlang/OTP 22.3', 'product': 'RabbitMQ', 'version': '3.8.3'}, mechanisms: [b'AMQPLAIN', b'PLAIN'], locales: ['en_US']
[2020-03-19 10:08:12,148: DEBUG/MainProcess] using channel_id: 1
[2020-03-19 10:08:12,157: DEBUG/MainProcess] Channel open
[2020-03-19 10:08:12,461: DEBUG/MainProcess] recreated blocker with handle 292
[2020-03-19 10:08:12,462: DEBUG/MainProcess] recreated blocker with handle 296
[2020-03-19 10:08:12,497: DEBUG/MainProcess] recreated blocker with handle 20
[2020-03-19 10:08:12,498: DEBUG/MainProcess] recreated blocker with handle 24
[2020-03-19 10:08:12,504: DEBUG/MainProcess] recreated blocker with handle 20
[2020-03-19 10:08:12,505: DEBUG/MainProcess] recreated blocker with handle 24
[2020-03-19 10:08:12,514: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] child process 9188 calling self.run()
[2020-03-19 10:08:12,554: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-4] child process 9072 calling self.run()
[2020-03-19 10:08:12,562: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-2] child process 1284 calling self.run()
[2020-03-19 10:08:12,602: DEBUG/MainProcess] recreated blocker with handle 20
[2020-03-19 10:08:12,606: DEBUG/MainProcess] recreated blocker with handle 24
[2020-03-19 10:08:12,665: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-3] child process 13412 calling self.run()
[2020-03-19 10:08:13,030: DEBUG/MainProcess] Timer wake-up! Next ETA 0.9840000000003783 secs.
[2020-03-19 10:08:13,244: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2020-03-19 10:08:13,245: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2020-03-19 10:08:13,246: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Gossip
[2020-03-19 10:08:13,246: DEBUG/MainProcess] using channel_id: 2
[2020-03-19 10:08:13,248: DEBUG/MainProcess] Channel open
[2020-03-19 10:08:13,267: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2020-03-19 10:08:13,267: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Tasks
[2020-03-19 10:08:13,486: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2020-03-19 10:08:13,487: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Control
[2020-03-19 10:08:13,488: DEBUG/MainProcess] using channel_id: 3
[2020-03-19 10:08:13,495: DEBUG/MainProcess] Channel open
[2020-03-19 10:08:13,518: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2020-03-19 10:08:13,519: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting event loop
[2020-03-19 10:08:13,522: INFO/MainProcess] celery@MY-LAPTOPS-NAME ready.
[2020-03-19 10:08:13,522: DEBUG/MainProcess] basic.qos: prefetch_count->16
[2020-03-19 10:08:14,023: DEBUG/MainProcess] Timer wake-up! Next ETA 1.0 secs.
[2020-03-19 10:08:15,027: DEBUG/MainProcess] Timer wake-up! Next ETA 1.0 secs.
[2020-03-19 10:08:16,028: DEBUG/MainProcess] Timer wake-up! Next ETA 1.0 secs.
...
```

Comment: Perhaps Windows firewall does not allow localhost connections?

Comment: I tried disabling it so I doubt that's it, unless disabling windows firewall in the settings somehow isn't enough.

Comment: try to connect amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672 manually and confirm that amqp is installed

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please check the update at the bottom of the question. @kkiat

Comment: Please provide your logging settings.

Comment: I added the output of the terminals to the bottom of the question. The only settings i'm setting manually is TASK_SOFT_TIME_LIMIT, the rest should all be default.

Answer (score 0):

The print function will be output to console according to django default settings. To output to the debugging screen, use logging instead of print function. So, The `tasks.py` should be as below:

```
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
from celery import shared_task

logger = get_task_logger(__name__)


@shared_task
def debug_task():
     logger.info("Task executed.")
```

Reference: 
https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#logging

Comment: After changing to this code and making the debug_task create a file, I still don't see any output on any terminal and the file is not being created, so it's likely the task is not being executed at all. What could cause this, given that celery worker does "see" the task?

Comment: You can monitor the task with celery flower